# Dependencies missing while building Mesa3d

Tags: package-management, dependencies, mesa

Meson was used,missing dependencies are as follows:

```
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
Dependency vdpau found: NO
Dependency xvmc found: NO
Dependency libomxil-bellagio found: NO
Dependency libtizonia found: NO
Dependency libtizplatform found: NO
Dependency tizilheaders found: NO
Dependency libva found: NO
meson.build:1088:0: ERROR: Native dependency 'zlib' not found
```

UPDATE:

```
libegl1-mesa:
  Installed: 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  Candidate: 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
libgl1-mesa-dri:
  Installed: 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  Candidate: 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
libgl1-mesa-glx:
  Installed: 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  Candidate: 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
N: Unable to locate package libglx-mesa
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What are you trying to compile? Please give URL for sources.

Comment: Im on Ubuntu 18.04.2, trying to compile Mesa3D. here is the source that i followed:   https://www.mesa3d.org/install.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. enable *Source code* repositories in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`)
2. get build-dependencies for [Mesa source package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic-updates/mesa):

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep mesa
   ```
3. retry the compilation method.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, I think i got slightly further with your method, however there is a new error message.    meson.build:1155:4: ERROR: Invalid version of dependency, need 'libdrm_intel' ['>=2.4.97'] found '2.4.95'.

Comment: What is your final target? Why are you trying to build Mesa from source? Why do you expect that latest source version from 2019 should compile normally on 2018 system?

Comment: Is there another way to compile it? is there an install package or is this the only way. My final target is just to get mesa installed

Comment: Mesa is core system package. So it is already installed. Please add output of `apt-cache policy libegl1-mesa libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglx-mesa` to the question.

Comment: Ok, ive updated the question.

Comment: Then what is your real problem? I do not understand it. Do you have problems with video playback, or what?

Comment: Clearly you are getting quite annoyed too trying to sort this out, i didn't know mesa was a core component, so i assumed that you had to install it manually, thats probably where the mis-communication was, thank you for your help so far, and im not gonna take up more of your time.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was somewhat rude, but next time visit https://packages.ubuntu.com first. And read something official [about software installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/addremove.html.en). Nowadays compilation is used very seldom, as many applications are packaged by Debian and Ubuntu maintainers. Hope this helps  :)